# Can you rephrase this sentence (about storing files)?

Tags: word-order, phrasing

> Starting from this date all such files will be stored in folder B.

Is it possible to re-phrase this sentence without changing its meaning in such a way that it would start from "Starting from this date the storing of all such files will ..."

Comment: "Starting from this date the storing of all such files will ..."

"...be in folder B." ??

Is that what you're looking for? It seems so simple that I wonder why you'd be asking for it. Do you just want confirmation that it is possible? The answers that don't use the gerund "storing" are attempting to make the whole sentence sound better rather than sticking to a forced context.

Comment: @Mitch - "*Starting from this date the storing of all such files will ..." "...be in folder B." ?? Is that what you're looking for?*" - Well, I think storing, while being a process, cannot really take place in a folder, that's why I thought that there should be some other words added before *in folder B* like *directed to* or something. I think Martha did an excellent job in this regard (please see her answer below).

Comment: To me, 'storing' does take place very naturally in a 'folder' in this context.

Comment: @Mitch - Then I think I didn't understand the English word "storing" correctly. For some reason I was taking *storing* in the same way as *firing* - while I can fire a bullet at Jack, I can't say that the action of firing that bullet took place in Jack.

Comment: Though it does involve the preposition 'in', 'Storing' is not particularly active here. Your intuition about 'firing' in English is correct. For 'storing' though, really, an item is not actually stored until it is 'in' its final location.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is certainly possible.

"Starting from this date the storing of all such files will be in folder B."
"Starting from this date the storing of all such files will be relegated to folder B."
"Starting from this date the storing of all such files will be specified for folder B."

However, all of these are awkward and less understandable than the original phrase. It changes the voice from active to passive, by making the verb "stored" into a gerund noun "storing". (Not it's not actually passive voice, but it's certainly a more passive phrasing.)

Comment: Thank you for this, Martha. That's exactly what I wanted to find out - whether or not it was possible to express that thought in that way regardless of the awkwardness.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it *is* possible without creating an ugly or ungrammatical sentence. The subject of the utterance is **the storing**, which must be modified by an adjectival phrase meaning *will be performed using folder B for storage*. Not easy to do without repeating oneself.

The original sentence is brief and precise. The only improvement I can see is that I personally would change *Starting* to *As*, and *will be* to *are*. Where there's no loss of clarity or accuracy, short words are always preferable - particularly in technical manuals & user guides.

I think this problem arises because logically the *real* subject of the utterance should be *all such files*, for which the attribute being specified is where they are stored. Introducing *the storage* (I don't like *storing* at all here) as an intermediate noun phrase simply makes the whole thing semantically and grammatically convoluted.

Answer (score 1):

IMO, a native English speaker would say "Beginning on [give the actual date, not "this date"], the system will store all such files in Folder B."

-- pete

Comment: @Pete - You can replace *Starting from this date* with *Beginning on [give the actual date]*, but, please, don't change anything else in the starting pattern that I have provided - it is important to me to see whether or not it is possible to express the same thought starting it that way. You have added the word *system* and have changed the meaning in doing so. In my sentence it is not clear whether the files are being stored by some system or it is done manually by humans.

Comment: Can you give some more context? Why is it so necessary to have exactly that beginning? Do you want it to remain unclear/ambiguous as to action by machine or human? And anyway all the assumptions of the situation don't lead to a change in meaning by adding 'the system'.

Comment: @Mitch - I don't have any context. I am just curious if its possible to express the same thought while having the word *storing* as the main subject of the sentence (not *files*).

Comment: @Mitch - "*And anyway all the assumptions of the situation don't lead to a change in meaning by adding 'the system'*" - Are you sure? What if, say, the files are being stored not by some software, but by a secretary in the office. Do you think the word *system* would still be applicable here?

Comment: @brilliant: OK, then, yes, it's possible grammatically with no problem, just stylistically, I agree with the others that one would prefer not to be forced to use 'storing'.

Comment: @brilliant: If you add 'system' to the original sentence, it doesn't change the meaning for me, because whatever a person is doing, it is the system that implicitly allows the placement. Sure, if you said 'the programmer' or 'the secretary', that would certainly be much more specific than the original sentence.

Comment: @Mitch - *...because whatever a person is doing, it is the system that implicitly allows the placement* - What if these files and folders are merely physical files and folders (not those on the computer disk)? And what if it's just a small office - not a big company that could be referred to as a system? What if it's simply an announcement written on a bulletin board in that office by that very secretary? Do you really think that adding the word *system* will not change the meaning in that case?

Comment: @brilliant -- I'm afraid I am just too dumb see how the gerund 'storing' can be the subject of any sentence like the one you started with. I'll be interested to your solution to this problem.

Comment: @Pete - Check Martha's answer. I think her answer provides best possible solutions.

Answer (score 1):

> Starting from this date all such files will be stored in folder B.

There is nothing wrong with this.

> Beginning on this date all such files will be stored in folder B.

Nothing wrong with this one either.

Nevertheless, I would probably phrase the sentence this way:

> As of this date all such files will be stored in folder B.

Comment: Thanks, but this is not really what I am asking about in my question.